# Constructor Injection - Do we inject factories as well?

Tags: dependency-injection, factory-pattern, constructor-injection

After listening to the [Clean Code Talks](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL693EFD059797C21E), I came to understand that we should use factories to compose objects. So, for example, if a `House` has a `Door` and a `Door` has a `DoorKnob`, in `HouseFactory` we create a new `DoorKnob` and pass it to the constructor of `Door`, and then pass that new `Door` object to the constructor of `House`.

But what about the class that uses the `House` *(say the class name is `ABC`)*? It will depend on the `HouseFactory`, right? So do we pass the `HouseFactory` in the constructor of `ABC`? Won't we have to pass a whole lot of factories in the constructor that way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Staying with the Door and DoorKnob example, you don't inject a factory - you inject the DooKnob itself:

```
public class Door
{
    private readonly DoorKnob doorKnob;

    public Door(DoorKnob doorKnob)
    {
        if (doorKnob == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("doorKnob");

        this.doorKnob = doorKnob;
    }
}
```

No factories are in sight in this level.

House, on the other hand, depends on Door, but not on DoorKnob:

```
public class House
{
    private readonly Door door;

    public House(Door door)
    {
        if (door == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("door");

        this.door = door;
    }
}
```

This keeps options open until at last you *have* to compose everything in the application's [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx):

```
var house = new House(new Door(new DoorKnob()));
```

You can use a DI Container to compose at this level, but you don't have to. No factories are involved.

Comment: thanks for the answer. a question about the composition root. What should be the composition root when it comes to an EJB call or a web service? Is it the called method itself?

Comment: Those are Java specifics with which I'm not familiar, but as a general concept composition happens very late: when you can't possibly postpone it any longer.

Answer (score 2):

If you inject too many factories that is a code smell called [constructor over-injection](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/01/20/RebuttalConstructorOverinjectionAntipattern.aspx) that indicates your class is doing too much.

Many containers provide a feature called auto-factories. That means they generate factories of type `Func<T>`automatically if they know how to generate `T`.

Castle Windsor has an advanced feature called [Typed Factory facilities](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories.ashx) which generates implementations of a factory interface on-the-fly.

There is also a port of typed factories for Unity in the [TecX project](http://tecx.codeplex.com).

Answer (score 0):

If you end up using Unity, I have recently implemented an equivalent of Castle Windsor Typed Factories for Unity. You can find the project at https://github.com/PombeirP/Unity.TypedFactories, and the NuGet package at  http://nuget.org/packages/Unity.TypedFactories.

The usage is the following:

```
unityContainer
    .RegisterTypedFactory<IFooFactory>()
    .ForConcreteType<Foo>();
```

You just have to create the IFooFactory interface with a method returning IFoo, and the rest is done for you by the library. You can resolve IFooFactory and use it to create IFoo objects straight away.